# How can I get tight_layout() in matplotlib to work with inset plots?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using matplotlib.pyplot to make a plot with several subplots. Here's what I ultimately want: a 2x2 array of "major" plots. Each of these have two curves in the plot, each using a different y axis. In addition, I want a smaller inset plot in each of these.

I've got the first part so far, using this working example code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os
import shutil
import time
import sys

#Simplest working example of tight_layout and plots problem

def two_scales(ax1, time, data1, data2, c1, c2, xlabel, y1label, y2label):

    ax2 = ax1.twinx()

    ax1.plot(time, data1, color=c1)
    ax1.set_xlabel(xlabel)
    ax1.set_ylabel(y1label)

    ax2.plot(time, data2, color=c2)
    ax2.set_ylabel(y2label)
    return ax1, ax2

# Change color of each axis
def color_y_axis(ax, color):
    """Color your axes."""
    for t in ax.get_yticklabels():
        t.set_color(color)
    return None

def insetPlots():

    t = np.arange(0.01, 10.0, 0.01)


    #Figure stuff
    fig, baseAxes = plt.subplots(2,2,figsize=(10, 6))
    baseAxesFlattened = baseAxes.flatten()


    for i, dat in enumerate(baseAxesFlattened):

        s1 = np.exp((i+1)*t)
        s2 = .3*np.sin((i+1)*.2 * np.pi * t)

        #Plotting them together
        tempAx1, tempAx2 = two_scales(baseAxesFlattened[i], t, s1, s2, 'b', 'r','heyheyhey','yayaya','woopwoop')

        #Changing the color of the axes
        color_y_axis(tempAx1, 'b')
        color_y_axis(tempAx2, 'r')


    plt.tight_layout()
    #plt.figure(figsize=(6, 8))
    picname="/mypath/testtesttest.png"
    plt.savefig(picname)

insetPlots()
```

Which produces this, good so far:

[image]

Now I want to add the insets. I can do this too fairly easily:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os
import shutil
import time
import sys

#Simplest working example of tight_layout and plots problem

def two_scales(ax1, time, data1, data2, c1, c2, xlabel, y1label, y2label):

    ax2 = ax1.twinx()

    ax1.plot(time, data1, color=c1)
    ax1.set_xlabel(xlabel)
    ax1.set_ylabel(y1label)

    ax2.plot(time, data2, color=c2)
    ax2.set_ylabel(y2label)
    return ax1, ax2

# Change color of each axis
def color_y_axis(ax, color):
    """Color your axes."""
    for t in ax.get_yticklabels():
        t.set_color(color)
    return None

def insetPlots():

    t = np.arange(0.01, 10.0, 0.01)


    #Figure stuff
    fig, baseAxes = plt.subplots(2,2,figsize=(10, 6))
    baseAxesFlattened = baseAxes.flatten()


    for i, dat in enumerate(baseAxesFlattened):

        s1 = np.exp((i+1)*t)
        s2 = .3*np.sin((i+1)*.2 * np.pi * t)

        #Plotting them together
        tempAx1, tempAx2 = two_scales(baseAxesFlattened[i], t, s1, s2, 'b', 'r','heyheyhey','yayaya','woopwoop')

        #Changing the color of the axes
        color_y_axis(tempAx1, 'b')
        color_y_axis(tempAx2, 'r')

        pos = tempAx1.get_position()
        #print(pos)
        posString = str(pos)
        x0Ind, y0Ind, x1Ind, y1Ind = posString.find('x0'),posString.find('y0'),posString.find('x1'),posString.find('y1')
        #print(x0Ind, y0Ind, x1Ind, y1Ind)
        x0, y0, x1, y1 = float(posString[x0Ind+3:y0Ind-2]), float(posString[y0Ind+3:x1Ind-2]), float(posString[x1Ind+3:y1Ind-2]), float(posString[y1Ind+3:-1])
        #print(x0, y0, x1, y1)

        mainPlotW = x1 - x0
        mainPlotH = y1 - y0

        w, h = 0.3*mainPlotW, 0.25*mainPlotH
        left, bottom, width, height = [x0 + .15*mainPlotW, y0 + .7*mainPlotH, w, h]
        insetAx = fig.add_axes([left, bottom, width, height])

        #insetAx.plot(range(6)[::-1], color='green')
        s3 = np.sin(.2 * np.pi * t/(i+1))
        insetAx.plot(t,s3, color='green')


    #plt.tight_layout()
    #plt.figure(figsize=(6, 8))
    picname="/mypath/testtesttest.png"
    plt.savefig(picname)

insetPlots()
```

Note that here I've commented out tight_layout(). This produces this, which has the inset plots in the positions I want them:

[image]

So this has the inset plots in the right positions, but because tight_layout() is gone, the axes labels for the major plots are overlapping. If I have tight_layout() (so, same exact code as directly above, but with that line uncommented), I get this:

[image]

Where the major plots' axes aren't overlapping anymore, but the insets are now in the wrong positions. I also get this warning when I run the code:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/figure.py:2022: UserWarning: This figure includes Axes that are not compatible with tight_layout, so results might be incorrect.
  warnings.warn("This figure includes Axes that are not compatible "
```

How can I make them both work? I suspect I'm doing something simple wrong, like placing insets in the wrong way.

EDIT: I've found a solution, but it's ugly and I hope not the "proper" way to do it. I suspected that tight_layout() is moving things around, so the positions of the inset plots (which depend on the positions of the major plots) were getting messed up relative to the major plots after tight_layout(). So I solved the problem by plotting the major plots, doing tight layout, and then adding the inset ones:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os
import shutil
import time
import sys

#Simplest working example of tight_layout and plots problem

def two_scales(ax1, time, data1, data2, c1, c2, xlabel, y1label, y2label):

    ax2 = ax1.twinx()

    ax1.plot(time, data1, color=c1)
    ax1.set_xlabel(xlabel)
    ax1.set_ylabel(y1label)

    ax2.plot(time, data2, color=c2)
    ax2.set_ylabel(y2label)
    return ax1, ax2

# Change color of each axis
def color_y_axis(ax, color):
    """Color your axes."""
    for t in ax.get_yticklabels():
        t.set_color(color)
    return None

def insetPlots():

    t = np.arange(0.01, 10.0, 0.01)


    #Figure stuff
    fig, baseAxes = plt.subplots(2,2,figsize=(10, 6))
    baseAxesFlattened = baseAxes.flatten()

    majorAxes = []

    for i, dat in enumerate(baseAxesFlattened):

        s1 = np.exp((i+1)*t)
        s2 = .3*np.sin((i+1)*.2 * np.pi * t)

        #Plotting them together
        tempAx1, tempAx2 = two_scales(baseAxesFlattened[i], t, s1, s2, 'b', 'r','heyheyhey','yayaya','woopwoop')

        majorAxes.append(tempAx1)

        #Changing the color of the axes
        color_y_axis(tempAx1, 'b')
        color_y_axis(tempAx2, 'r')


    plt.tight_layout()

    for i, dat in enumerate(baseAxesFlattened):

        tempAx1 = majorAxes[i]
        pos = tempAx1.get_position()
        #print(pos)
        posString = str(pos)
        x0Ind, y0Ind, x1Ind, y1Ind = posString.find('x0'),posString.find('y0'),posString.find('x1'),posString.find('y1')
        #print(x0Ind, y0Ind, x1Ind, y1Ind)
        x0, y0, x1, y1 = float(posString[x0Ind+3:y0Ind-2]), float(posString[y0Ind+3:x1Ind-2]), float(posString[x1Ind+3:y1Ind-2]), float(posString[y1Ind+3:-1])
        #print(x0, y0, x1, y1)

        mainPlotW = x1 - x0
        mainPlotH = y1 - y0

        w, h = 0.3*mainPlotW, 0.25*mainPlotH
        left, bottom, width, height = [x0 + .15*mainPlotW, y0 + .7*mainPlotH, w, h]
        insetAx = fig.add_axes([left, bottom, width, height])


        #insetAx.plot(range(6)[::-1], color='green')
        s3 = np.sin(.2 * np.pi * t/(i+1))
        insetAx.plot(t,s3, color='green')


    #plt.tight_layout()
    #plt.figure(figsize=(6, 8))
    picname="/mypath/testtesttest.png"
    plt.savefig(picname)

insetPlots()
```

[image]

Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: seems like you arrived at the same conclusion as I did. I did not see your EDIT while I was posting. In any case, I do think that's the "proper" way to deal with your particular situation

Answer (score 1):

`tight_layout()` is just a useful tool for most common plots, but it cannot deal with every situation.

In your particular case, I think you are better off calling `tight_layout()` *before* creating your inset axes, and  using the resulting axes position to find the correct coordinates for your insets

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os
import shutil
import time
import sys

#Simplest working example of tight_layout and plots problem

def two_scales(ax1, time, data1, data2, c1, c2, xlabel, y1label, y2label):

    ax2 = ax1.twinx()

    ax1.plot(time, data1, color=c1)
    ax1.set_xlabel(xlabel)
    ax1.set_ylabel(y1label)

    ax2.plot(time, data2, color=c2)
    ax2.set_ylabel(y2label)
    return ax1, ax2

# Change color of each axis
def color_y_axis(ax, color):
    """Color your axes."""
    for t in ax.get_yticklabels():
        t.set_color(color)
    return None

def insetPlots():

    t = np.arange(0.01, 10.0, 0.01)


    #Figure stuff
    fig, baseAxes = plt.subplots(2,2,figsize=(10, 6))
    baseAxesFlattened = baseAxes.flatten()


    for i, ax in enumerate(baseAxesFlattened):

        s1 = np.exp((i+1)*t)
        s2 = .3*np.sin((i+1)*.2 * np.pi * t)

        #Plotting them together
        tempAx1, tempAx2 = two_scales(ax, t, s1, s2, 'b', 'r','heyheyhey','yayaya','woopwoop')

        #Changing the color of the axes
        color_y_axis(tempAx1, 'b')
        color_y_axis(tempAx2, 'r')

    fig.tight_layout()

    for i, ax in enumerate(baseAxesFlattened):
        pos = ax.get_position()
        #print(pos)

        mainPlotW = pos.x1 - pos.x0
        mainPlotH = pos.y1 - pos.y0

        w, h = 0.3*mainPlotW, 0.25*mainPlotH
        left, bottom, width, height = [pos.x0 + .15*mainPlotW, pos.y0 + .7*mainPlotH, w, h]
        insetAx = fig.add_axes([left, bottom, width, height])

        insetAx.plot(range(6)[::-1], color='green')
        s3 = np.sin(.2 * np.pi * t/(i+1))
        insetAx.plot(t,s3, color='green')


insetPlots()
```

[image]

**PS** You're doing some pretty weird things with the `pos` variable, transforming it to `str` before casting it back to `float`. I've simplified your code in the second loop in my code

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Regarding the pos variable, I did that because get_position returned a "bbox" object that I didn't know I could just grab the x1/etc members from, so I did a very ghetto thing of parsing the string to get the numbers... that seems smarter though.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using [`mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator.InsetPosition`](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/axes_grid/api/inset_locator_api.html#mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator.InsetPosition) to position the inset. This simplifies things a lot, not needing to multiply plot sizes with anything.

You may then choose to call `fig.tight_layout()` before or after creating the insets, the resulting plot will not change (though calling it after gives a warning, which you can ignore in this case).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import InsetPosition
import numpy as np

def two_scales(ax1, time, data1, data2, c1, c2, xlabel, y1label, y2label):

    ax2 = ax1.twinx()

    ax1.plot(time, data1, color=c1)
    ax1.set_xlabel(xlabel)
    ax1.set_ylabel(y1label)

    ax2.plot(time, data2, color=c2)
    ax2.set_ylabel(y2label)
    return ax1, ax2

# Change color of each axis
def color_y_axis(ax, color):
    """Color your axes."""
    for t in ax.get_yticklabels():
        t.set_color(color)
    return None

def insetPlots():

    t = np.arange(0.01, 10.0, 0.01)
    #Figure stuff
    fig, baseAxes = plt.subplots(2,2,figsize=(10, 6))
    baseAxesFlattened = baseAxes.flatten()

    for i, ax in enumerate(baseAxesFlattened):

        s1 = np.exp((i+1)*t)
        s2 = .3*np.sin((i+1)*.2 * np.pi * t)
        #Plotting them together
        tempAx1, tempAx2 = two_scales(ax, t, s1, s2, 'b', 'r',
                                      'heyheyhey','yayaya','woopwoop')
        #Changing the color of the axes
        color_y_axis(tempAx1, 'b')
        color_y_axis(tempAx2, 'r')

    fig.tight_layout()

    for i, ax in enumerate(baseAxesFlattened):

        insetAx = fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1], label="{}".format(i))
        ip = InsetPosition(ax, [.15, 0.7, 0.3, 0.25]) #posx, posy, width, height
        insetAx.set_axes_locator(ip)

        insetAx.plot(range(6)[::-1], color='green')
        s3 = np.sin(.2 * np.pi * t/(i+1))
        insetAx.plot(t,s3, color='green')

    # putting tight_layout here will produce a warning, 
    # yet the resulting plot is the same
    # fig.tight_layout() 


insetPlots()
plt.show()
```

[image]